# How can I list my questions marked as needed improvement in Quora?

Tags: quora

I wonder how I can list my all questions marked as needed improvement in Quora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now there is no such way. You can only list all your questions by clicking **Questions** on your profile.